# How to fix ESLint error Use array destructuring

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a line in my code :

```
this.someVar = document.querySelectorAll("div[container-type='some-container']")[0];
```

ESLint check throws error for this line 'Use array destructuring'.
How can I fix this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
([this.someVar] = document.querySelectorAll("div[container-type='some-container']"));
```

Comment: Added brackets to make clear that its an expression, while omitting them would work here, it wouldnt work with object destructuring ,`{0: someVar} = [...]` would be a syntax error. However feel free to rollback / omit them if you prefer that.

Comment: This solution worked for me on this context.
I had `this.mainSource = Object.keys(this.sourcesList)[0];` and using your solution I ended up like this: `[this.mainSource] = Object.keys(this.sourcesList);` 
Do you mind explaining me this solution? I would like to understand it.

Comment: This solution will assign the variable `this.mainSource`  to the first value in the array generated by`Object.keys(this.sourcesList)` , and if you want to assign the second value of the array you will do that `[ , this.mainSource] = Object.keys(this.sourcesList)` and so on

Answer (score 3):

set `prefer-destructuring` array to false: 
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring